# ¿Por que es ineficiente usar SELECT * FROM?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Hace poco leí un párrafo que decía que hacer un s`elect * from...` era muy ineficiente a diferencia de cuando señalamos los campos que queremos usar, pero  necesito más información en cuanto a eso.

¿Alguien me podría decir dónde encontrarla o alguna experiencia que haya tenido en cuanto a esto?

Comment: en donde lo leiste?

Comment: Ese es el punto, fue buscando algo sobre unas consultas y no me acuerdo donde.

Comment: Creo que estás confundiendo el término, tu duda es si es más eficaz o eficiente?

Comment: Correcto, el termino es eficiente. gracias

Comment: Si haces un select en una tabla, es la unica manera que YO conozco para obtener datos, pero fijate que las cosas cambian cuando utilizas relaciones con otras tablas ya que es mas eficiente el uso de Joins

Comment: Segun lo que lei era mas eficiente hacer: "select a, b, c, from..." que hacer un: select * from. Supuestamente si no recuerdo mal, es por que entonces mysql tiene que leer el nombre de los campos y hacer un proceso que en el momento ignore por que no era lo que yo estaba investigando,  total, segun eso, cuando la consulta es de muchos campos, aunque sean 100, para mysql es mas rapido que especifiquemos los datos. aclaro, eso segun lo que yo leí.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cuando se utiliza * equivale a usar la clausula ALL que selecciona todos las columnas. Esto hace que no se utilizan los indices definidos.
Vera, los indices se definen sobre una o varia columnas (pocas) de una tabla o vista posibilitando que SQL recupere de forma mas veloz y eficiente las filas y  asociadas a los valores definidos en la clave de ese indice.

Ademas el solo hecho de cargar una gran cantidad de datos sin restricción hace que que el motor de base de datos y los demás elementos que intervienen deben realizar un esfuerzo mayor manejar esa gran cantidad de datos que tal vez no sea necesaria.

En SQl Server se desaconseja usar * porque el motor de base de datos va a la tabla maestra y consulta los nombres de las columnas antes de realizar la consulta y luego la ejecuta. Esto supone un doble proceso. 
Probablemente sea un caso similar en Mysql

Esta dirección contien información que quizás le sea útil: http://www.awerty.net/telemantenimiento/realizar-consultas-en-sql/

Comment: Gracias compañero, esto es lo que habia estado buscando

Comment: Cuidado con esta respuesta. Tiene mucha información dudosa. Por ejemplo: *Esto hace que no se utilizan los indices definidos.* ¿Tienes alguna referencia para esto? Porque esto no es cierto.

Comment: Es mi análisis. Lo he comparado y es mi deducción.  la documentación de las bases de datos sugieren crear indices para optimizar las consultas. No parece tener sentido un indice de todos los campos de una tabla. Si ese fuera el caso para que indexes? Si se hace una consulta no indexada sencillamente no se usan los indices previstos porque no coinciden. Me encantaría saber su contra argumento quizás pueda aprender.

Comment: Esta respuesta parecería estar comparando el caso de una consulta que selecciona todos los campos versus una selección de ***algunos*** campos (no todos), pero esa no es la pregunta. Específicamente cuando se menciona "*cargar una gran cantidad de datos sin restricción*" habla de una diferencia en cantidad de datos, condición que no se cumpliría si se seleccionan todas las columnas.

Answer (score 1):

Realizar una consulta sólo con los campos que necesitas sí es más eficiente que consultar todos los campos.

Cuando consultas sólo los campos que necesitas la base de datos se encargará de obtener y devolver sólo la información que le solicitastes. Entre más información tenga de devolver la base de datos más durará en responder.

Comment: Sin embargo, la pregunta compara seleccionar **todos** los campos explícitamente o con `*`

Comment: Pues yo veo la pregunta y dice exactamente 
"**select * from... era muy ineficiente a diferencia de cuando señalamos los campos que queremos usar**". Señalar los campos que queremos utilizar es diferente a seleccionar todos los campos.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que hay una confusión con el uso o no de los índices. Intentaré dar mi opinión sobre la pregunta que era sobre la conveniencia o no de usar SELECT * FROM..

Nunca se recomienda usar SELECT * FROM por varias causas

1.- A pesar de que es una práctica cómoda, puede provocar que en el futuro una aplicación no funcione correctamente. Imagínate una tabla con los campos A,C F. Si tú haces un SELECT * entonces la respuesta traerá 3 campos; pero si añades el campo B después de la A (quedando campos A,B,C,F), el mismo SELECT "recorrerá" los campos C y F un lugar. Si tu programa usa los campos por posición (despliega el campo 2) entonces todo fallará.

2.- La lectura puede ser más lenta. Imagínate una tabla con 30 campos (no es raro) y solo necesitas realmente 3 campos ¿qué crees que se tarde más y ocupe más espacio?... exacto, el SELECT * tendrá que leer 30 campos del disco y transferirlos al programa en lugar de leer solo 3 y transferir 3.

3.- En el caso de los índices puede ser incluso beneficioso si todos los campos que quieres extraer están en la llave del índice: Si haces un SELECT de 2 campos, y esos dos campos están en un índice, entonces solo leyendo el índice se puede responder todo el SELECT; por el contrario, si haces un SELECT * entonces el motor de bases de datos tendrá que -quizá- usar el índice y luego hacer el "salto" al disco para extraer el resto de los datos (en SQL Server se llaman lookups cuando ves el plan de ejecución).

4.- SQL Server, específicamente, puede hacer uso de unos índices CLUSTER que incluso te ayudan mucho más, pero sería materia de otra pregunta. Quizá MYSQL tiene algo similar.

Espero haber contribuido.

Answer (score 0):

Sólo sería ineficiente en el caso de que no necesites todas las tuplas.

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar en qué te estás basando para afirmarlo?

Answer (score -4):

Se usa select nombre, apellidos FROM tabla; cuando queremos extraer únicamente una selección de campos en concreto y es de menor cantidad, para añadirlos a una tabla o a un formulario etc.; pero si lo que queremos es rellenar un formulario de 30 campos no es muy lógico realizar la consulta seleccionando los campos en cuestión.
Un ejemplo para entender: tenemos la tabla datos y tenemos 200 campos:
nombre, edad, telefono, direccion, cp, email, ciudad, pais, etc....
¿Qué vamos a seleccionar uno a uno los 200 campos, para ello mejor ponerlos todos con *?

Espero que te sirva de ayuda mi información.

Comment: Pero estuve leyendo que el motor de mysql asimila mucho mas rapida la consulta cuando se especifica el nombre de los campos, de lo contrario le toca hacer un proceso que ralentiza la consulta.

Comment: Esto es erróneo, aunque vayas a seleccionar 50 campos mejor escribir uno a uno los que quieres, hasta 50... Tú te ahorras unos minutos escribiendo 50 campos, pero obligas al motor de base de datos a hacer los 200 SELECT cuando pones `SELECT *...` .